# If AND OR function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I write a function to do the following logical test: If column D is "D or E or F" and column E is 0 then show 1. If column D is " A or B or C" and column E is 1 then show 0.

Comment: Your condition list is not complete. What should be shown when neither condition is true?

Comment: Likewise, what about if E is 0 and D=A (and all other cases)?

Comment: other possibilities are not clinically possible, they never occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IF(AND(OR(D1="D",D1="E",D1="F"),E1=0),1,IF(AND(OR(D1="A",D1="B",D1="C"),E1=1),0,"<action when neither before is true>"))`

Comment: Good answer you are just missing the closing brackets `))`

Answer (score 0):

If when column = 1 then column D will equal "A","B",or "C" and vice versa.
so just do `IF($E3=1,0,1)`.

This should work if all "other possibilities are not clinically possible, they never occur"